# UserDefaults - defaults...?

Tags: swift

I made this generic class which helps me reading values from user defaults. Besides it abusing several `UserDefaults`... what do you see? Can I make some instances share a reference?

```
class DefaultValue<V> {
    var userDefaults = UserDefaults()
    let name : String
    let defValue : V

    init(name: String, defValue: V) {
        self.name = name
        self.defValue = defValue
    }

    func get() -> V {
        if userDefaults.object(forKey: name) == nil {
            return defValue
        }
        switch defValue {
        case is Int:
            return userDefaults.integer(forKey: name) as! V
        case is Bool:
            return userDefaults.bool(forKey: name) as! V
        case is String:
            return userDefaults.string(forKey: name) as! V
        default:
            return defValue
        }
    }

    func set(value: V) {
        userDefaults.set(value, forKey: name)
    }

    func reset() {
        userDefaults.set(defValue, forKey: name)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class MyDefaults {
    let LOGGED_IN = DefaultValue<Bool> (name: "logged_in", defValue: false)
    let USERNAME = DefaultValue<String> (name: "username", defValue: "")
}

var settings = MyDefaults()
if settings.LOGGED_IN.get() {
    settings.LOGGED_IN.set(value: true)
} else {
    settings.LOGGED_IN.reset()
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forced casts `as! V` in the `get()` method might seem safe at first
sight, since you do some type-checking before. But they are not:
If a default value for some key exists, but is of the wrong type then
your program can crash. This can for example happen if you change the
type of some default value between program releases. You can easily
reproduce the problem by setting the default value to an incompatible
type before retrieving it with your class:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set([1, 2, 3], forKey: "username")

class MyDefaults {
    let USERNAME = DefaultValue<String> (name: "username", defValue: "Joe")
}

print(MyDefaults.USERNAME.get())
```

which crashes at

```
return userDefaults.string(forKey: name) as! V
// Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This can be avoided with optional casting `as? V`, and then the
entire `get()` method simplifies to

```
func get() -> V {
    return userDefaults.object(forKey: name) as? V ?? defValue
}
```

As a bonus, the code now works not only with integers, booleans and
strings, but with all types (provided that they are “UserDefaults compatible”).

---

I do not see a reason to create separate `UserDefaults` instances,
you can share the standard instance:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
```

---

The `reset()` method could simply remove the value instead of setting
the default value:

```
func reset() {
    userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: name)
}
```

A possible advantage is that you can retrieve it with a different
default value later.

---

I would use “default” as argument label in the init method:

```
init(name: String, default defValue: V) {
    self.name = name
    self.defValue = defValue
}
```

That looks nicer when called

```
let USERNAME = DefaultValue<String> (name: "username", default: "")
```

and also mimics the [`subscript(_:default:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript) of Swift dictionaries.

The `set()` method should have an empty argument label

```
func set(_ value: V) {
    userDefaults.set(value, forKey: name)
}
```

like, for example, [`set(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414067-set).

---

If your intention of `class MyDefaults` is to avoid global variables
and to provide a “namespace”: This can also be achieved with a
case-less `enum`:

```
enum MyDefaults {
    static let USERNAME = DefaultValue<String>(name: "username", default: "")
}

MyDefaults.USERNAME.set("elcuco")
print(MyDefaults.USERNAME.get())
```

so that no instances have to be created.

---

*Naming:* According to the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#general-conventions):

> Names of types and protocols are `UpperCamelCase`. Everything else is `lowerCamelCase`

so it should be

```
enum MyDefaults {
    static let loggedIn = DefaultValue<Bool> (name: "logged_in", default: false)
    static let userName = DefaultValue<String>(name: "username", default: "")
}
```

instead of `LOGGED_IN` and `USERNAME`.

Comment: Accepted all your suggestions, besides the `UserDefaults.standard` suggestion, which is not something I want to leave to the user of this .."library". See my new proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Lets add a new constructor:

```
init(name: String, default defValue: V, userDefaults: UserDefaults) {
    self.name = name
    self.defValue = defValue
    self.userDefaults = userDefaults
}
```

I don't like the idea of imposing a default settings on programmers using this library. New usage should look like this:

```
enum Settings {
    static let userDefaults = UserDefaults()
    static let loggedIn = DefaultValue<Bool> (name: "logged_in", default: false, userDefaults: userDefaults)
    static let userName = DefaultValue<String> (name: "username", default: "", userDefaults: userDefaults)
}
```